# How to retrieve the instance of a chart that is not global

Tags: chart.js

I am creating like 10 charts with chart.js like this:

```
    new Chart(document.getElementById("chart01"), {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: data,
      options: options
    });

    new Chart(document.getElementById("chart02"), {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: data,
      options: options
    });
```

As you can see, I am not using a `var chart01 = new Chart(...` because I do not want have all these charts globally.

However, I do know the canvas id's to which the charts are assigned to. So how can I use this canvas id to get the chart instance and update it?

This code gives me all Chart instances, but I do not know how to assign a chart instance directly.

```
    Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance){
      console.log(instance.chart);
    })
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I never use this idea/trick (It's easier to work with global charts).

Anyway, one option is to put ([if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)) or ([Switch Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)) inside the loop:

```js
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance){
  if (instance.chart.canvas.id === "chart_1") {
    console.log("id:"  + instance.chart.canvas.id +"|" + instance.chart.data.datasets[0].data[1]);
  }
  if (instance.chart.canvas.id === "chart_2") {
     /* do something */
  }
})
```

In my opnion this code is not "so clean" (For 10 charts). I prefer to use `new` constructor (Maybe someone else got "cleaner" solution). 
Anyway this idea will work fine.

### Code example - update chart_1 value

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig

`chart_1` Update the dataset value of `february` from `30` to `50`:

```js
var chart_1 = document.getElementById('chart_1');
new Chart(chart_1, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',
  responsive: true,
  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [20, 30, 45]
    }]
  },
  // Configuration options go here
  options: {}
});

var chart_2_node = document.getElementById('chart_2');
new Chart(chart_2, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'bar',
  responsive: true,
  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: ['April', 'May', 'June'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Second dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(22, 22, 22)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(22, 22, 22)',
      data: [0, 10, 5]
    }]
  },
  // Configuration options go here
  options: {}
});

Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance){
  if (instance.chart.canvas.id === "chart_1") {
    console.log("id:"  + instance.chart.canvas.id +" | February before update: " + instance.chart.data.datasets[0].data[1]);
    instance.data.datasets[0].data[1] = 50; // Would update the second dataset's value of 'February' to be 50
    instance.update(); // Calling update now animates the position of February from 30 to 50.
  }
  if (instance.chart.canvas.id === "chart_2") {
     /* do something */
  }
})
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>chart 1</h4>
  <canvas id="chart_1"></canvas></section>
<section>
  <h4>chart 2</h4>
  <canvas id="chart_2"></canvas>
</section>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

You can use this idea to update any value/option of the chart instance.
**Example:** change the type from `bar` to `line`:

```
    instance.config.type = "pie";
    instance.update(); //
```

Comment: Thanks @Ezra Siton. This will work for sure. But I agree, it is not the most "clean" solution, but it workw. And using a return once the if condition was met and all code inside run will make it "cleaner". But still looking forward to other suggestions as well.